# Connection timeout expired in centos 7 without load

Tags: centos7, connection-timeout

I have a vps on which I run my telegram bot. My bot has like 10 messages a second. regularly my cpu load is between 50 and 70 and it works fine. sometimes, like now, cpu load drops on 0% or 1% (Like there's nothing to do, While there's a queue of 10K messages pending) and doesn't accept any new request. even if I enter my domain address it won't open my home page (May be it opens it after 60 seconds). What's the problem for? How can I solve it?
By the way, I contacted the company that I bought my server from, And they said there's no connection issues and they're right, Because at the same time I can open netstat page or kloxo control panel and I have no problem with that.

[image]

webserver: apache
Php: 5.6
Dns server: bind
Thanks